# Can you prevent writing code over and over again with small differences?

Tags: java, android

I am using a specific block of Java code allot, currently on 1 page i use it over thirty times. This is because in every block of code all the numbers need to go up by 1 for every comparison I make. (example 1) Is there a way to write some code that increases the numbers in use by 1 (like you'd normally use an increment code). If so is this also possible when calling resources (example 2)

specific block of code:

```
//        Comparison 1
    if (Uinput1.equals(answer1)) {
        edit1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00FF00"));
    }
    else {
        edit1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
    }
```

second use and so on.

```
//        Comparison 2
    if (Uinput2.equals(answer2)) {
        edit2.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00FF00"));
    }
    else {
        edit2.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
    }
```

declaring resources etc.

```
 private String answer1;
 private String answer2;`

 this.answer1 = getString(R.string.answer1);
 this.answer2 = getString(R.string.answer2);`

 this.answer1 = getString(R.string.answer1);
 this.answer2 = getString(R.string.answer2);

 this.edit1 = findViewById(R.id.edit1);
 this.edit2 = findViewById(R.id.edit2);

 String Uinput1 = edit1.getText().toString();
 String Uinput2 = edit2.getText().toString();
```

**EDIT:**

I used this for the first part:

`private String[] answers = {"example", "example"}`

Comment: probably use arrays

Comment: A) java code is "famous" for boilerplate, especially in android setups but then B) as soon as you start naming things a1, a2, ... you probably should use arrays or lists, or some sort of container.

Comment: The comparison has 3 things that differ (UinputX, answerX, editX). Write a method that takes these three things (or their corresponding resource IDs) as parameters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quite often when you see numbers in your variable names (i.e float var1), it is a good time to use an array instead.

In this case, you could use arrays like this:

```
private String[] answers = new String[2];
```

or

```
private String[] answers = {"foo", "bar"}
```

You can then access each index of the array like this:

```
System.out.println(answers[0]); //prints "foo"
```

Alternatively, you can use a for loop to perform an action on every index of the array.

```
for(int i = 0; i < answers.length; i++){
  System.out.println(answers[i]);
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer, it works fine. Now i tried to do this:  `private EditText[] edits = {findViewById(R.id.edit1), findViewById(R.id.edit2)};` This code does not give any errors but when i run the app it closes on start up. Is this a viable way of doing so if possible? And if so also in this example? `String Uinput1 = edits[1].getText().toString();`

Comment: Hmm, I can't see any problems in this line other than you might be able to use an array for `R.id.edit1` and `R.id.edit2`. Could you please send more code in a [Hastebin](https://hastebin.com/)?

Comment: I found out what the problem is I got a `NullPointerException` (again). My code looked like that because it was a workaround for it, so thats why it works with the strings but not for the `findViewById`.                                                          As my target whas to loop the comparison it's not a priority to put the EditTexts in an array. So if you really feel like it you can look into it, but it's not necessary.

Answer (score 2):

you can do something like:

```
function(a,b,c){
if (a.equals(b)) {
    c.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00FF00"));
}
else {
    c.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));  }
```

}

Comment: This is exactly the right idea, but the syntax is a little awry.  Also, single-letter variable names are seldom a good idea.

Comment: This should be marked the right one, just change your variable names.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways you can avoid repeating lines of code

**1.Arrays**: You can use arrays in your case quiet easily

```
int inputs=2;
String[] Uinput=new String[inputs]
String[] Answers=new String[inputs]
EditText[] Edit=new EditText[inputs]
```

and you could initialize them with for loops

```
for(int i=0;i<inputs;i++){
 int resID = getResources().getIdentifier("answer"+(i+1), "id",getPackageName());
 Edit[i]=((EditText) findViewById(resID));
 Uinputs[i]=Edit[i].getText().toString();
 resID=getResources().getIdentifier("edit"+(i+1), "string",getPackageName());
 Answer[i]=getResource(resID)
}
```

Comparison becomes easy you just have to manipulate the value of i

```
if (Uinput[i].equals(Answer[i])) {
    Edit[i].setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00FF00"));
}
else {
    Edit[i].setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
}
```

**2.Functions**: You could use functions for the comparision part but it would be difficult for the declaration

```
void Compare(String Uinput,String answer,EditText edit){
    if (Uinput.equals(answer)) {
       edit.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00FF00"));
    }
    else {
       edit.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
    }

}
```

I myself use Functions to reduce duplication but in yiur case it would be much ,ore sensible to use arrays. You could combine the two by using arrays and just while calling the function use the values of the arrays as parameters

```
 Compare(Uinput[i],Answer[i],Edit[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd stay away from arrays in this case, if only because HashMaps were made for this sort of comparison. If you saved your question / answer pairings in a hashmap, you'd be able to create a method that accepts a question and an answer string, and returns a boolean indicating whether there's a match. This would reduce the complexity you're seeing, and prevent the need for all those extra string declarations.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but I've already declared the arrays and looped the comparison. Currently this will fit mine needs. If however, I would rewrite the code I will surely look into it.